# unit test for catch block using kotlin mockito

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit, mockito, try-catch

```
    try {
    return Response.ok(payHandler.getFeesForPay(body, config)).build()
    }



    catch (e: Exception) {
    return exceptionHelper.buildResponseFromException(e)
    }
```

How to write unit test using mockito for code in catch block

Answer (score 0):

Without a more detailed code, all we can suggest you is to mock `payHandler` to throw an exception as follows:

```java
when(payHandler.getFeesForPay(any(), any()))
   .thenThrow(NullPointerException.class);
```